# Javascript or JQuery how to replace all '+' in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, numbers

Right now I have a variable which is storing a string.

```
var value = "66+88";
```

How can I replace '+' with a standard + operator  so that I can evaluate

> 66 + 88 = 154

Thanks

Comment: can you show what you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it to get `Number` and then [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var value = "66+88";
var result = value.split('+').map(Number).reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}, 0);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) for this:

```
var value = eval("66+88");
```

But you need to be careful, especially if this string come's from user.

This function will evaluate input string as JavaScript and can damage your other scripts or can be used for hacker attacks.

**Use it at your own risk!**

Comment: You can but the way the OP asked question doesn't make me believe that they would understand the dangers of this way.

Comment: @CherryDT What is danger of `eval`?

Comment: That it can execute arbitrary JavaScript. Depending where the OP gets this string from in the first place, this can either cause unexpected behavior or more serious XSS issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String#replace`

```js
var value = "66+88";
var result = value.replace(/^(\d+)\+(\d+)$/, function(x, y, z){
             return parseInt(y) + parseInt(z) })
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() method to split the string.

```
var value = "66+88";
var no = value.split('+');
console.log(parseInt(no[0]) + parseInt(no[1]));
```

**split()** method will return an **array**. In this case

> no = ['66','88']

**parseInt()** will convert string to Int and you can calculate the sum.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split` and `reduce` to sum up your string.

Here is an example.

```js
var value1 = "66+88";
var value2 = "66+88+44";


function sumUpStr (strToSum) {
  var sum = strToSum.split("+").reduce(function(prev, next) {
    return +prev + +next;
  });
  return sum;
};


console.log("Sum of value1 is: " + sumUpStr(value1));
console.log("Sum of value2 is: " + sumUpStr(value2));
console.log("Sum of value1 + value2 is: " + sumUpStr(value1 + "+" + value2));
```